# flutter how to screen eye-care mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, native

I want user can switch screen to eye-care mode for better reading like example .

An example :

[image]

for change to dark mode i used following method :

```
ThemeData buildLightTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
  return base.copyWith(
    cardColor: kLightBgLight,
    ...
    );
}

ThemeData buildDarkTheme() {
  final ThemeData base = ThemeData.dark();
  return base.copyWith(
    brightness: Brightness.dark
    cardColor: kDarkBgLight,
    ...
    );
}
```

and use in MaterialApp Theme like that :

```
theme: Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: false).darkTheme
                  ? buildDarkTheme()
                  : buildLightTheme(),
```

Comment: your book reader looks nice, do you mind telling which SDK did you use in flutter?